# Error when I use recursion to get more than 4 perfect numbers JAVA

Tags: java, recursion, runtime-error, stack-overflow, perfect-numbers

I'm using an algorithm with recursion to calculate 30 perfect numbers, but only calculates the first 4 and then the program throws an error.

[image]

```
public class PerfectNumbers {
  /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    getPerfectNumbers(1,1);
  }

  static void getPerfectNumbers(long out,long number) {
    long total = 0;
    if(out==30) {
      return;
    }
    for ( int i=1;i<number;i++) {
      if(number%i==0) {
        total+=i;
      }
    }
    if(total==number) {
      System.out.println("Perfect Number "+number);
      out++;
    }
    number++;
    getPerfectNumbers(out,number);  
  }
}
```

What's wrong with the algorithm?

Comment: the recursion never ends, so stackoverflow error happens.

Comment: It is not that it never ends, the size of the iterations is very large, it is something completely different, because the logic is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perfect numbers start by :

> 6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336

Performing `8128` nested invocations with a method that accepts two `long` parameter is generally feasible for the JVM.
I precise "two parameters" as the size of the stack matters in the number of nested invocation accepted by the JVM.
But from a some level of nested invocation, the JVM throws an `Error` : `java.lang.StackOverflowError` that is defined as :

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses
>   too deeply.

And `33550336` invocations nested are bound to be too much.

The algorithm is probably correct but you should favor loop over recursivity to prevent the overflow of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The 5th perfect number is so big that the amount of recursions it takes to reach it results in a [StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror). Manually checking every single number technically works, but is far from optimal as even the 5th perfect number is 33550336, which would take far longer than reasonable to calculate. A more efficient technique would be to check if the number can be represented by `2^(p-1)*(2^p-1)`, where `p` and `2^p-1` are prime. However, with that said, you are almost certainly going to be unable to calculate 8 perfect numbers, let alone 30, with a recursive or loop technique, simply because the numbers get far too big very quickly.